# Why don't we see the transverse waves with a phonon lattice dynamic while we see them with linear elasticity theory?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, fourier-transform, elasticity, phonons

Let's say that we have a lattice with particles sitting on the nodes. Each particle $n$ has neighbors $\bar n$:

$$\dfrac{d^2\boldsymbol u_n}{dt^2}=-K\sum_{\bar n}\boldsymbol u_{\bar n}\tag{1}$$

The term in the RHS corresponds to one definition of a discrete laplacian on the lattice considered.

In Fourier space with periodic boundary condition, the equation must reads:

$$\dfrac{d^2\boldsymbol u(\boldsymbol k)}{dt^2}=-K\omega(\boldsymbol k)\boldsymbol u(\boldsymbol k)\tag{2}$$

With $\boldsymbol k$s discrete and $\omega(k)$ is proportional to the dispersion relation.

**Main remark 1: We only have one dispersion relation: which I guess corresponds to the longitudinal wave?**

Now, we might turn to the theory of linear elasticity. In general we can write down the a quadratic energy ([see for example here](https://physicscourses.colorado.edu/phys7450/phys7450_sp15/lectureNotes/lecture2ElasticityPhonons.pdf)):

$$U = \dfrac{1}{2}\int (d^3k)\boldsymbol u(\boldsymbol k) \cdot \boldsymbol D(\boldsymbol k)\cdot\boldsymbol u(\boldsymbol k)\tag{3}$$

Where $\boldsymbol D (\boldsymbol k)$ is the dynamical matrix and which eigenvalues are the dispersion relations of the lattice.

Even for an isotropic lattice (which also describe hexagonal lattice in 2D), you obtain two different eigenvalues since (see the same link above):

$$D(\boldsymbol k) = \mu k^2 \boldsymbol P^T(\boldsymbol k)+(2\mu+\lambda)k^2\boldsymbol P^L(\boldsymbol k)\tag{4}$$

With $P^T$ and $P^L$ the projector according to the longitudinal or transverse direction and $\mu$ and $\lambda$ the Lamé's parameters.

**Main remark 2: We have, in 2D, 2 (on a general basis) distinct dispersion relations predicted from linear elasticity theory.**

---

**My question: How can we reconcile the "two theories" (which really seem to be the same)? Why the lattice usual dynamics predicts only one dispersion relation while the linear elasticity correctly predict the existence of longitudinal and transverse waves? Is it because the lattice theory is too simple and only include one spring constant (then both transverse and longitudinal modes might have the same dispersion relation?)? But why would an ISTROTROPIC linear elasticity theory manage to predict two branches while a discrete theory cannot?**

Comment: There are multiple branches of phonon dispersion relations, they are typically called LA for longitudinal acoustic, TO for transverse optic, etc. See figure 16 [here](http://perso.neel.cnrs.fr/xavier.blase/SSP2020/chapter6b.pdf) for an example phonon band structure of silicon.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the link! If we focus only on lattice dynamics with one spring constant $K$ and one type of atom to only look at the acoustic modes. The lattice theory never predicts two different branches (in 2D) for the transverse and the longitudinal direction right? It just gives one dispersion relation?

Comment: No, why? See [this example](https://www.phys.uni-sofia.bg/~vpopov/elbsphds2phsi.htm) for silicene, where you get L, T, Z modes. Granted, this model still has optical phonons, but I don't think this is so important.

Comment: @Ruslan Hum, ok. My "never" might have been to strong. Maybe a better question is: 'why Eq (1) or (2) in my post do not predict two dispersion relations (in 2D) but only one: $\omega(k)$? Is it because, in this model the longitudinal and the transverse waves have the same dispersion relation/velocity?

Comment: Your equation (1), if converted to a continuous form by taking the appropriate limit, will be a very special case of the Navier-Cauchy equation, where the Lamé parameters $\lambda=-\mu,$ which results in omission of the $\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})$ term, thus making all modes have the same dispersion relation (as in the vacuum EM wave equation).

Comment: @Ruslan Ah perfect, it answers my question!